# JavaScript Ternary Statements

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('navBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('navBtn').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.getElementById('navBtn').className = document.getElementById('navBtn').className == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
    document.getElementById('nav').className = document.getElementById('nav').className == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" - that would depend on what you expect, and want, that JavaScript to do and what it's doing instead. Please: read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: The ternaries themselves look fine. You might want to use `===` instead of `==`, but the construction is correct.

Comment: FYI, you can use `this` instead of `document.getElementById('navBtn')` inside the handler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `false` as the third parameter to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Mostly, it defaults to `false`, but it is better to have it on the safer side.

```js
document.getElementById('navBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('navBtn').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById('navBtn').className = document.getElementById('navBtn').className == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
  document.getElementById('nav').className = document.getElementById('nav').className == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
}, false);
```

```css
.x {
  color: #ccf;
}
.o {
  color: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBtn">Hi</div>
<div id="nav">Bye</div>
```

It is advised that you wrap the conditions in ternary inside `()` parentheses:

```
document.getElementById('navBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('navBtn').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById('navBtn').className = (document.getElementById('navBtn').className == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
  document.getElementById('nav').className = (document.getElementById('nav').className == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
}, false);
```

Comment: *"For some browsers..."* Really? Which ones?

Comment: @squint I read it somewhere. Getting the source. Searching for it. I definitely know this was a problem. Coz personally I faced it.

Comment: There are operator precedence issues that can come into play, but it isn't browser-dependent.

Comment: @squint I'll remove that line then. You remove the downvote. LoL.

Comment: @squint Done... Can I haz an upvote?

Comment: I won't remove the vote because the information you're posting is mostly irrelevant. The missing `false` parameter will only be an issue in really, really old versions of Firefox.

Comment: @squint Yes, what if the OP uses very old version of Firefox?

Comment: Uh, huh... I'm *sure* that's the problem here.

Comment: @squint Let's wait for what OP says. If OP's issue gets solved, then?

Comment: I agree, wait before answering instead of throwing out highly unlikely guesses that'll just confuse the issue.

Comment: @squint And I am 10000% sure OP will never return back! `:(` Happened to me today for most of the questions I answered.

Comment: That does happen quite a bit.

Comment: @squint Today's personal experience. `:(`

Comment: This is why it is advised to *not* answer those types of questions, and is also why closed or on hold questions disallow answers. There is no way to verify that any amount of change will cause the OP's minute amount of example to work in its actual context.